# trapping a jplayer error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Using jplayer 2.  When a user comes to our website and trys to play a video, a 'media could not be loaded' error occurs if they are using an older version of IE and do not have Adobe Flash installed.  I would like to be able to test for this condition and send them to the Flash site download site instead of allowing the generic error to occur.

Here is the video call:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    errorAlerts: true,
    ready: function ()
    {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: "http://www.parrotsoftware.com/default/videos/parrotcamproj.m4v",
            poster: "http://www.parrotsoftware.com/default/videos/peopleall.png"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    solution: "html,flash",
    supplied: "m4v"
});
```

Here is the active link:  http://www.parrotsoftware.com/default/default.aspx  click the play button in the video player.

Comment: It seems the video it's trying to load [isn't there](http://www.parrotsoftware.com/default/videos/ps.m4v)?

Comment: try to use www.longtailvideo.com/​players/​jw-flv-player if u want handle any parameter !

Answer (score 14):

just bind an error callback.. and test 'event.jPlayer.error.type', see: http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-error-codes

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    errorAlerts: true,
    ready: function ()
    {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: "http://www.parrotsoftware.com/default/videos/parrotcamproj.m4v",
            poster: "http://www.parrotsoftware.com/default/videos/peopleall.png"
        });
    },
    error: function (event) {
        console.log(event.jPlayer.error);
        console.log(event.jPlayer.error.type);
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    solution: "html,flash",
    supplied: "m4v"
});
```